# Is this considered undefined behaviour x = ++x % 5;

Tags: c, c99, sequence-points

I've been working on embedded C project, and I found code:

```
x = ++x % 5;
```

Now, first of all there are 2 side effect operators on variable x in one expression, assignment and prefix increment operator.

According to C99 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:TC3):

**Section 6.5 Expressions**

> 2. Between  the  previous  and  next  sequence  point  an  object  shall  have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

this should be considered as undefined behavior, but I haven't succeeded to prove that in practice.
Tried few compilers on windows (mingw32-gcc, msvc) and on linux:

```
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
Ubuntu 18.04 4.15.0-36-generic
```

So my question is, is this considered undefined behavior in embedded, and is it safe to use this in embedded?

Comment: What does the assembly say?  If you are really worried, compare the assembly generated by this (potentially unsafe) method and a non-side-effect method and see if it's worth worrying about.

Comment: Whether it's undefined or not, it's better to just write `x = (x+1) % 5;`

Comment: @Neil this would be the prove that this one specific compiler does not exploit the undefined behavior (if it is one), not that it is not undefined behavior.

Comment: Never write pointless code like this.

Comment: @interjay I know it's better, and I would never write it like `x = ++x % 5`. I would write it as you mentioned.

Comment: The C99 standard gives ` i = ++i + 1;` as an example of an undefined statement (footnote 73).

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yeah, it's not my code, I found it and I've been wondering is this considered undefined behavior.

Comment: Embedded systems makes no difference. If anything, various oddball embedded compilers are _more_ prone to go bananas when they encounter UB.

Comment: Note: with `int x; ... (x+1) % 5` results are in the range [-4 ... 4].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I compile the code on `gcc`, it shows me

> ```
> source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
>  source_file.c:8:7: warning: operation on ‘x’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
>       x = ++x % 5; 
>         ^
> ```

That's the first proof, that this *may* be UB.

To add to that, the increment (write operation, a.k.a, stored value modification) and assignment (once again, write operation, a.k.a, stored value modification) happens *without* a sequence point in between, so this is undefined behaviour.

That said, just write

```
  x = (x + 1) % 5 ;
```

Much better, readable, and [lessens the threat on your life](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.c++/rYCO5yn4lXw/oITtSkZOtoUJ).

Comment: I dare say that the _intention_ of `x = ++x % 5;` is properly carried out. Indeed there is a dead store that may be ignored, or carried out, but the result is the same. Would you agree?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I wont bet on it. :)

Comment: Related: A comment below the other deleted post: _"There's nothing to say that the increment is done before the modulo. A compiler is perfectly free to rewrite that into x = (__temp = (x + 1) % 5, x = x + 1, __temp) and then eliminate the dead store in x = x + 1, converting the whole expression into x = (x + 1) % 5 — in fact, most compilers will do just that when optimizing. The modulo uses the incremented value as operand, but the actual increment of the value need not happen before the modulo. –  **aaaaaa123456789** "_